# How can I replace a line which contains only -------- by |||

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have something like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | username | 2011-01-16 16:52:23 +0100 (Sun, 16 Jan 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /foo
Removed foo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | username | 2011-01-16 16:51:03 +0100 (Sun, 16 Jan 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /foo
created foo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My target is to identify the file added by the "username" in a specific date. Thus, I need to have the combination (username, 16 Jan 2011, A) to insure that it is the right file ands then print foo.
My idea is to:

1. delete the white spaces
2. change the newlines into |
3. get rid of the --------------- and replace them with newlines

but the problem is that I couldn't replace the ------- since they are mixed with other characters.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|r2|username|2011-01-1616:52:23+0100(Sun,16Jan2011)|1line|Changedpaths:|D/foo|Removedfoo|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|r1|username|2011-01-1616:51:03+0100(Sun,16Jan2011)|1line|Changedpaths:|A/foo|createdfoo|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I thought it would be a good idea to start by replacing the --------------- by a special character like ||| and then change this character by a newline using awk FS=||| OFS=\n
Can anyone help me!
thanks

Comment: If you want to replace the string of `-` with newlines then why not replace them with newlines instead of a special character first?

Comment: `--+` finds the long lines of dashes, can you show your regular expression?

Comment: cat file.txt| awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}{print $i}'|awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"}{if ($0~ username) {print $0}}'|tr -d " "| sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g'

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="--+"} {$1=$1}RT' OFS="|"  file
```

Comment: Very concise, me gusta.  Any reason you didn't throw `FS` and `RS` outside of BEGIN like `OFS`? Also, is `RT` a gawk'ism? And finally, it needs a bit of `gsub` love to meet the "Remove Spaces" requirement.

Comment: no, there's no special reason. OFS can be inside BEGIN as well. RT is gawk feature. as for remove spaces, i missed that requirement. But i don't really why he should spaces. anyway....if spaces need to be removed, then yes, a bit of gsub will do it

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^-+$/{print a[i++];next}!/^-+$/{gsub(/ /,"");a[i]=a[i] "|" $0}' infile
```

#### Output

```
$ awk '/^-+$/{print a[i++];next}!/^-+$/{gsub(/ /,"");a[i]=a[i] "|" $0}' ./infile

|r2|username|2011-01-1616:52:23+0100(Sun,16Jan2011)|1line|Changedpaths:|D/foo|Removedfoo
|r1|username|2011-01-1616:51:03+0100(Sun,16Jan2011)|1line|Changedpaths:|A/foo|createdfoo
```

Comment: @mimou OK, gensub requires `gawk` (GNU Awk). I'll rewrite to make it not need it.

Comment: @mimou Updated answer to not need `gawk`

Answer (score 0):

How about the following,

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$#" != '3' ] ; then
    echo "usage $0 logfile username date"
    exit 1
fi

cat "$1" | awk '
BEGIN{
    FS="|";
}

/------------------------------------------------------------------------/{
    username="";
    date="";
    next;
}

/^r[0-9]+/{
    username = gensub(/^ *(.*[^ ]) *$/, "\\1", "", $2);
    date = gensub(/^ *(.*[^ ]) *$/, "\\1", "", $3);
    next;
}

/^created /{
    filename = gensub(/^created /, "", "", $0);
    if ( username == "'"$2"'" && date == "'"$3"'" ) {
        print filename;
    }
}
'
```

If the following is executed on the input data,

```
$ ./script data username '2011-01-16 16:51:03 +0100 (Sun, 16 Jan 2011)'
```

the output is

```
foo
```

Hope that helps,
- Luke